# Like functionality on apps when signed in through facebook

Tags: facebook-like

here is our idea. We are just implementing Facebook authentication on our mobile apps (android/iphone)

The idea is to first show the user a "Sign-in " via facebook screen. Once the user signs-in via facebook, I want to ask him whether he would choose to like our business page, since he is already signed in. The user then simply clicks yes or like and he automatically likes the page (as in a facebook app)

I want to ensure though that I dont use a web view or anything and I dont want to ask the user for any additional FB authorization

Can this be done

Thanks

Comment: Yes it can be done. Do you need anything else? Do you want us to write the code for your idea?

Comment: Thanks Manuel. no actually just wanted to know which facebook apis etc to use to make this happen.